# TypeError: StructType can not accept object '1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM' in type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I want to create a simple dataframe in PySpark. This datframe should contain a timestamp string "1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM" that later I want to convert from string into timestamp.

This is my current code. When I run it, I get the error "TypeError: StructType can not accept object '1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM' in type". How can I fix it in such a way that finally I can successfully execute `to_timestamp`?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField

schema = StructType([
    StructField("timestamp_str", StringType(), True)
])

data = [("1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

df = df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp("timestamp_str", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))
```

**Update:**

After changing `data = [("1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM")]` to `data = [("1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM",)]` I get another error. It appears when I run `df.show()`:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3
> in stage 2.0 (TID 10) (10.233.49.69 executor 0):
> org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException:
> [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You
> may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:

Comment: the data should be a list of tuples -- `data = [("1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM",)]` -- notice the comma.

Comment: @samkart: Thanks, please see the update where I address it.

Comment: i get parsed result using `'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a'` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new column id and drop it after you create df. Spark throws an error when you create a one column df.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

schema = StructType([  StructField("id", StringType(), True),StructField("timestamp_str", StringType(), True)])

data = [('1',"1/1/2021 1:00:00 AM")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema).drop('id')

df= df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp("timestamp_str", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))

df.show()
```